# Import namespace - Cannot resolve the name to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Context: I am generating xsd files using Eclipse. All my .xsd files are in a single location - Project/ directory.

Problem: Everything works fine when xsd's don't reference/import other xsd's with a different target namespace. However when the following xsd below (with `namespace="http://www.example.org/experimento"`) imports another xsd `lugar_experimento.xsd` from a different namespace (`namespace="http://www.example.org/lugar_experimento"`), I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve the name xxx to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Here is my XSD (`experimento.xsd`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/experimento"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/experimento"
xmlns:lugar="http://www.example.org/lugar_experimento" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import schemaLocation="lugar_experimento.xsd" namespace="http://www.example.org/lugar_experimento"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="experimento">
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="identificador" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="lugar" type="lugar:tipoRefGeografica"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>      
</xsd:schema>
```

And I want to use the following XSD:' to 'And I want to use the following XSD (saved in `lugar_experimento.xsd`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/lugar" 
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/lugar" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:complexType name="tipoRefGeografica">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="W3Cgeo" type="tns:tipoW3Cgeo" />
        <xsd:element name="kml" type="tns:tipoKml" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="tipoKml">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d\.{0,1}\d*\s\d+\.{0,1}\d*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="tipoW3Cgeo">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="lat" type="xsd:decimal" />
        <xsd:element name="long" type="xsd:decimal" />      
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

What I am doing wrong? Do you have any easy example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `experimento.xsd`, Change this:

```
xmlns:lugar="http://www.example.org/lugar_experimento"
```

to:

```
xmlns:lugar="http://www.example.org/lugar"
```

The problem is the difference between the namespace URIs ^^.

Comment: Additionally, in the `xsd:import`, `namespace="http://www.example.org/lugar_experimento"` should be change to `namespace="http://www.example.org/lugar"`. The namespace you import must match one defined in the file you are importing.